# Substitute a variable in a line read from a file

Tags: bash

I have read the config file which has the below variable:

```
export BASE_DIR="\usr\usr1"
```

In the same script I read a file line by line and I wanted to substitute the `${BASE_DIR}` with `\usr\usr1`.

In the script:

```
while read line; do
echo $line 
done <file.txt
```

`${BASE_DIR}\path1` should be printed as `\usr\usr1\path1`

Tried `eval echo` and `$(( ))`.

Answer (score 0):

Can use sed, This command will search and replace a value.  The dollar sign is the separator.

```
sed -ie 's$\${BASE_DIR}$\\usr\\usr1$1' hello.txt
```

Comment: @Aavik `echo $(...)` is redundant.

Comment: I think he wants to replace `${BASE_DIR}` with the value of the variable, not a string that's hard-coded into the script.

Comment: @melpomene I have echo $(...) as I wanted this content to write to a file. echo $(eval echo ${line})  > file1. Is there a better way of doing?

Comment: @Aavik Yes, just remove `echo $( ... )` and do `eval echo "${line}" > file1`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the variable when you read the line that contains the assignment. Then you can replace it later.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
    if [[ $line =~ ^BASE_DIR= ]]
    then basedir=${line#BASE_DIR=}
    fi
    line=${line/'${BASE_DIR}'/$basedir}
    printf "%s\n" "$line"
done < file.txt > newfile.txt
```